# getting error while running hive jobs with oozie in

Tags: hive, oozie

```
Status: Failed
Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1470692453676_0866_1_00, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1470692453676_0866_1_00_000000, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: tez.runtime.io.sort.mb 2048 should be larger than 0 and should be less than the available task memory (MB):2048
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:92)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.sort.impl.ExternalSorter.getInitialMemoryRequirement(ExternalSorter.java:327)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.output.OrderedPartitionedKVOutput.initialize(OrderedPartitionedKVOutput.java:93)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask$InitializeOutputCallable._callInternal(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:505)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask$InitializeOutputCallable.callInternal(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:487)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask$InitializeOutputCallable.callInternal(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:472)
        at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
], TaskAttempt 1 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: tez.runtime.io.sort.mb 2048 should be larger than 0 and should be less than the available task memory (MB):2048
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:92)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.sort.impl.ExternalSorter.getInitialMemoryRequirement(ExternalSorter.java:327)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.output.OrderedPartitionedKVOutput.initialize(OrderedPartitionedKVOutput.java:93)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask$InitializeOutputCallable._callInternal(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:505)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask$InitializeOutputCallable.callInternal(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:487)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask$InitializeOutputCallable.callInternal(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:472)
        at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
], TaskAttempt 2 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: tez.runtime.io.sort.mb 2048 should be larger than 0 and should be less than the available task memory (MB):2048
```

Comment: I recommend you to assign some tez memory settings for hive and retry , this link might be useful https://documentation.altiscale.com/memory-settings-for-tez

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the sort buffer size to its default value
 `tez.runtime.io.sort.mb=512`

in your hive-site.xml and retry

Comment: Thanks Addy. It worked for me . i reset the value of this property to tez.runtime.io.sort.mb=1024 as it was recommended in my cluster. TQ